# File download x-server

Tags: php, windows, download, fileserver

I have the following setup:

- 1 Webserver
- 4 Windows fileservers

All are in the same domain, and on the same network (10.13.1.)

How do I go about letting a user download a file from a fileserver without first having to store the file on the webserver?

The aim is that a user can go to a URL (let's say http://download/?server=1&path=/relative/path/to/file.zip) which goes to file \FILESERVER1\relative\path\to\file.zip

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: If you know the server, and you know the path, why can't you just use the full real path?